# TCP Socket Java (server) and python (client)

Tags: java, python, sockets

Trying to send a file through a java server and python client.

#### Client.py

```
from socket import socket


def main():
    s = socket()
    s.connect(("localhost", 6030))


while True:
    f = open("archivo.txt", "rb")
    content = f.read(1024)

    while content:
        # Enviar contenido
        s.send(content + '\n')
        content = f.read(1024)

    break


# Cerrar conexión y archivo.
s.close()
f.close()
print("El archivo ha sido enviado correctamente.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

#### Server.java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {
public static void main (String []args) {
               try { 
                      ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(6030); 
                      Socket s = ss.accept(); 
                      DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream()); 
                      String k = dis.readUTF(); 
                      System.out.println("File Transferred"); 
                      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\yo.txt"); 
                      byte[] b = k.getBytes(); 
                      fos.write(k.getBytes()); 
                     } catch (IOException ie) { 
                       ie.printStackTrace(); 
                     }
          }
}
```

It gives this error:

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
at Server.main(Server.java:10)
```

Appreciate any help. I have the python server and java client and it works just fine. Also, they work well between python client-server and java client-server

Comment: This is mostly to do with your end of file handling. Your java server is trying to do a read from a closed file

Comment: "readUTF" expects a particular data format, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readUTF()

Comment: `readUTF()` only understands data that was written by `writeUTF()`, and you don't have such a thing in Python. Just read and write the bytes. And get rid of the added newline when sending, and the `chr(1)` to signal end of stream. Closing the socket already does that. You're making no attempt to handle that properly in the receiving code anyway. And you can't assume you will get the whole file in a single read.

Comment: @user207421 I see but, how can I do that? I have no idea :(

Comment: @abdullahalali how can I solve it? :(

Comment: I've answered that. There seems to be an epidemic of asking people to repeat themselves this week. Read what I wrote. It's in there.